# Converting a callback to a suspendCoroutine, when the callback is a field of class

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-lateinit

I want to convert some 3rd-party API based on callbacks to simple suspend functions that are easy to use. Here's a simplified example of mine implementation.

```
class LibraryWrapper {

    private lateinit var onFooFired: (Boolean) -> Unit

    private val libraryCallback = object : LibraryCallback {
        override fun foo(result: Boolean) {
            onFooFired(result)
        }
    }
    private val library = Library(libraryCallback)

    suspend fun bar(): Boolean {
        return suspendCoroutine { performingBar: Continuation<Boolean> ->
            onFooFired = {fooResult -> performingBar.resume(fooResult) }
            library.bar()
        }
    }
}
```

But this solution sometimes works and sometimes not. There is such an issue with this lambda field, that sometimes it initializes correctly, but sometimes the exception is thrown that ***"lateinit property onFooFired is not initialized"***.

It's very strange because I do initialize it before run library.bar() and foo of LibraryCallback is called ***only after*** library.bar() was called.

Comment: It seems from your code that you need to initialize onFooFired() before you create Library object with your callback, not only before calling library.bar().

Comment: @OritMalki, I've also tried to initialize it with an empty value
`private var onFooFired: (Boolean) -> Unit = {}`
and after that, it didn't throw an exception, but called this empty implementation.

Comment: sounds like it's the way to go. Or, if you have some constraints preventing you from initializing it before the Library, if the Library's callback is public or you have a method to add/set it to the library, initialize the library's callback before calling bar().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, I think it is not a good approach to use "lateinit var" when you don't control the initialization of a field. Use lateinit only when you have the promise of initialization.

Try to use nullable field implementation like

```
private var onFooFired: ((Boolean) -> Unit)? = null
```

and in callback :

```
private val libraryCallback = object : LibraryCallback {
        override fun foo(result: Boolean) {
            onFooFired?.invoke(result)
        }
    }
```

In this case, until you do not have an implementation of "onFooFired" lambda, it does not invoke